# Can't import with IntelliJ SBT console

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, console, sbt

I installed Intellij's official SBT plugin (still in alpha), I imported without a problem a Scala SBT project (with build.sbt). But when I try to import something in the Scala console it prints this: 
        `<scala>  import recfun.Main._
        <console>:7: error: not found: value recfun
            import recfun.Main._`

But when I launch exactly the same command with SBT running in the terminal it works fine.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I found the following helped. I was working on a program imported using the SBT plugin, that had **multiple sub-projects**. This may also work if you have a native IntelliJ project with multiple modules.

Go to the menu "run -> Edit configurations ...", select `Scala Console`, and then in the box that says "Use classpath and SDK of module", pick the sub-project that has the `build.sbt` with the import statements you need (in my case `server`):

[image: The edit configs window]

The import appeared to work after that.